# Person in "pelvis cloth"

Tags: word-meaning, expressions

What is a person in "pelvis cloth"?

What kind of clothing is that?

In what context is this expression used?

Comment: Google "pelvis cloth". Click on "images". Ignore the anatomy models for childbirth. Have your answer.

Comment: @Stephie: I actually did that before asking the question. The images do not show the inner workings of that cloth, nor do they tell what it is made of, not what is their functional goal. For some reason this cloth lost its appeal, at about the same time as photography appeared it seems, so the only few pictures we have are very narrowly focussed on Greek sports nostalgia. Not easy to extract a general definition from these. A definition from a dictionary of that time (or even a recent dictionary) would be great :-)

Answer (score 2):

A pelvis cloth appears to be a more elaborate loincloth, the latter being, according to the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/loincloth),

> A single piece of cloth wrapped round the hips, typically worn by men
>   in some hot countries as their only garment.

You can see it in Eadweard Muybridge's famous movement sequence photographs, like [this one](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Man_in_pelvis_cloth_posing_%28rbm-QP301M8-1887-321%29.jpg).